# Une exception de type 'System.Reflection.TargetException'

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a question about an exception given below:

> System.Reflection.TargetException

so, first of all, I wish developed a generic method for the add methods in the database but I have a problem in this ligne so my genericADD :

```
namespace MyProjectWPFMVVM.ViewsModels{
class PropertiesVMTypeItem : ViewModelBase
{
  public   int idTypeItem {
      get { return idTypeItem; }
      set
      {
          idTypeItem = 10;
          OnPropertyChanged("idTypeItem");
      }
  }
    public string DesignationTypeItem
    {
        get { return DesignationTypeItem; } 
        set
        {
            DesignationTypeItem = "sss";
            OnPropertyChanged("DesignationTypeItem"); }
    }
    public int MaxNumberConnectionsTypeItem
    {
        get { return MaxNumberConnectionsTypeItem; }
        set
        {
            MaxNumberConnectionsTypeItem=1;
            OnPropertyChanged("MaxNumberConnectionsTypeItem"); }
    }
}}
//and for my class model :
namespace MyProjectWPFMVVM.Models{  
public partial class im_type_items
{
    public im_type_items()
    {
        this.im_characteristics_items = new HashSet<im_characteristics_items>();
        this.im_items = new HashSet<im_items>();
    }

    public int idTypeItem { get; set; }
    public string DesignationTypeItem { get; set; }
    public byte[] SymbolTypeItem { get; set; }
    public  int MaxNumberConnectionsTypeItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<im_characteristics_items> im_characteristics_items { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<im_items> im_items { get; set; }
}}//and this is my appel methode in VM :
public void GenericAjoutt(){
IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesForModel = 
GenericAjout.GetPropertiesForModel<im_type_items>();
        IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesForView = GenericAjout.GetPropertiesForView<PropertiesVMTypeItem>();
        var newTypeItem = GenericAjout.CreateNewRowInModel<im_type_items>(propertiesForView, propertiesForModel);
        ImItemsModel.SaveChanges();


    }//and my problem is : namespace MyProjectWPFMVVM.Method 
{public static class GenericAjout
{


    private static Dictionary<Type, IList<PropertyInfo>> ModelDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, IList<PropertyInfo>>();
    public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesForModel<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!ModelDictionary.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            ModelDictionary.Add(type, type.GetProperties().ToList());
        }
        return ModelDictionary[type];
    }
    private static Dictionary<Type, IList<PropertyInfo>> ViewPropertiesDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, IList<PropertyInfo>>();
    public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesForView<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!ViewPropertiesDictionary.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            ViewPropertiesDictionary.Add(type, type.GetProperties().ToList());
        }
        return ViewPropertiesDictionary[type];
    }
    public static T CreateNewRowInModel<T>(IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesView, IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesModel  ) where T  : new() 
    {
        T item = new T();
            foreach (var p in propertiesView)
            {
                foreach (var property in propertiesModel)
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, p.GetValue(property.Name)); // erreur L’objet ne correspond pas au type cible, ou une propriété est une propriété d’instance mais obj a la valeur null.
                }
            }
            return item;
    }

}
```

}

so please help.
i edit the problem 
so the is property.SetValue(item, p.GetValue(property.Name)); // erreur L’objet ne correspond pas au type cible, ou une propriété est une propriété d’instance mais obj a la valeur null.

Comment: Which line throws that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to follow, but if I understand correctly, it boils down to this:

```
foreach (var p in propertiesView)
{
    foreach (var property in propertiesModel)
    {
        property.SetValue(item, p.GetValue(property.Name)); // erreur L’objet ne correspond pas au type cible, ou une propriété est une propriété d’instance mais obj a la valeur null.
    }
}
```

That is, when you call `property.GetValue()`, you get an exception reporting that the object you passed in does not have the correct type for the property you're trying to set.

Which makes sense given the code, which appears to be passing a `string` value as if that was the object on which the property exists. Even if that's fixed, you have another problem, which is that for each property in the `propertiesView` list, the code tries to use the value for that property and set *each* property in the `propertiesModel` list. E.g. it tries to use the value retrieved from the `idTypeItem` property in source object, by setting *every* property of the target object to that value.

It seems to me that instead, you should pass in the object for which you want the properties copied from, and want to only set the property if the names are the same. For example:

```
public static T CreateNewRowInModel<T>(
    IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesView, IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesModel, object source)
    where T : new() 
{
    T item = new T();

    foreach (var p in propertiesView)
    {
        object value = p.GetValue(source);

        foreach (var property in propertiesModel)
        {
            // Optional, not shown:
            // For added security, check that the types are the same also

            if (property.Name == p.Name)
            {
                property.SetValue(item, value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

I don't see in your code where the `source` parameter value would come from, but presumably you do have a view object in mind that you can pass to the method. Otherwise, where did you think those values would have come from?